# Trouble with Oracle date format

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

**Query 1: Redundant to_date usage:**

```
SELECT 1
FROM dual
WHERE '22-APR-2018'>add_months(to_date(
  (to_date('28-02-2018' ,'dd-mm-yyyy') ) ,'dd-mm-yyyy'),60);
```

--

**Query 2: Single to_date usage:**

```
SELECT 1
FROM dual where '22-APR-2018'>ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('28-02-2018' ,'dd-mm-yyyy'),60);
```

In any case, these queries must not return data, since 22-APR-2018 is never greater than 28-FEB-2023.

But **Query 1** returns data. I do not understand oracle functionality here.

Comment: there is absolutely no need to use `select` to provide a constant value.

Comment: It could have been avoided. Didn't notice it as i was just trying to simulate the problem as it is in my application script. Question edited now.

Comment: why are you applying to_date() on something that is already a DATE? Never do that; when you do, you force Oracle to covert the date into a string so it can be converted back to a date again, and it uses the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter to work out what format mask to use. This can cause issues in the conversion if your date string is not in the expected format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with this code. One of them is:

```
to_date((to_date('28-02-2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy')), 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

or without the double-bracketing:

```
to_date(to_date('28-02-2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

`to_date()` takes a string argument, so Oracle has to convert the date it got from `to_date('28-02-2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy')` into a string. So implicitly it's

```
to_date(to_char(to_date('28-02-2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy')), 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

What does `to_char(to_date('28-02-2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy'))` give you? It will depend on your `nls_date_format`, which often defaults to `DD-MON-RR`, in which case you'll get `28-FEB-18`, and converting that back to a date with a `YYYY` year format gives 28th Feb 0018 (Oracle implicitly interprets `FEB` to match `MM`), which is before 22nd April 2018.

Oracle also implicitly converts the string in the comparison to a date, again using the default date format, so although it's obviously a bad idea to compare a string to a date and hope for the best, in this case you get away with it.

In Oracle we write date literals as

```
date '2018-04-22'
```

and not

```
'22-APR-2018'
```

So the right way to write this would be

```
select 1
from   dual
where  date '2018-04-22' > add_months(date '2018-02-28', 60);
```

which gives no rows.

Comment: Crisp explanation! `date '2018-04-22'` seems to be the technical way but oracle seems to be comfortable with '22-APR-2018' too. For example:Below query also works good `SELECT 1
FROM dual
WHERE '22-APR-2018'>add_months(to_date('28-02-2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy') ,60); ` Any idea what happens internally?

Comment: When you force Oracle to convert a string to a date, it uses the default date format and language for your session, so again you may get away with `’22-APR-2018’` for now with your current default settings, but one day when you least expect it, maybe years from now, it won’t do what you expect.

Comment: @Vivek To add to what William has said, if you run `alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyymmdd';` in your session and then rerun your query, you'll find that it won't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

'22-APR-2018' is not a `date` it is a string.  So both sides of the condition get implicitly converted to strings and 'APR' < 'FEB'.

Use `to_date` on it or (easier) an ANSI literal instead so that you are comparing `date` values:

```
SELECT 1
FROM dual where DATE '2018-04-22'>ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('28-02-2018' ,'dd-mm-yyyy'),60);
```

Comment: `SELECT 1
FROM dual
WHERE to_date('22-04-2018','dd-mm-yyyy')>add_months(to_date(
  (SELECT to_date('28-02-2018' ,'dd-mm-yyyy') FROM dual) ,'dd-mm-yyyy'),60);`  this query with `to_date` also says 22-apr-2018 is greater than 22-feb-2023

Comment: So now you've introduced a spurious `select to_date(...) from dual` that returns a date, and then applied `to_date` to that which forces Oracle to implicitly convert it to a string first... Don't do that!

Comment: @VIVEK : just check step by step what's happening. Here it is actually comparing  `22-04-2018`   >  `28-02-0023` due to implicit conversion , which is true

Comment: @KaushikNayak ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('28-02-2018' ,'dd-mm-yyyy'),60) returns 2023. Why do you mention 0023?

Comment: @vivek not this. In Ur previous comment.